# Performance Profiling for HTML5 Javascript Game

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling

There are lots of profiling and unit test library for javascript.
Unfortunately most of them are for regular web site.

I want to profile javascript performance in very detail especially for game using canvas.
As far as I know, best tool for profiling is chrome's "Profiles tab"and console.profile function which are very helpful, but not enough.

For example, I had to write code just for counting number of calls of function.

```
// counter pattern(?)
Function.prototype.counter = function( counterName ) {
    var invokeFunction = this;
    return function() {
        addCounter( counterName );
        invokeFunction.apply( this, arguments );
    }
}
// register counter function
classObject.prototype["Function1"] = classObject.prototype["Function1"].counter( "ClassA.Function1" );
```

Is there any better tools for profiling?

Comment: Why is the chrome profiler not enough? In what way is it not effective? Also, have you considered the possibility that instead of the javascript being the slow point, that it could be a browser issue instead?

Comment: Hi, I'm searching for the exact same thing, did you find something along your way? or you ended up writing your own profiling library?

Comment: Sorry for delayed comment. I could not find best solution for this. I just have to satisfy chrome profiler.